# Unwanted margin on the right hand side of the website

Tags: css

I'm attempting to make my website cross-browser and resolution compatible, but for some reason I get an odd white space on the right hand side of my website when the window is resized? It's fine if it's full screen in my native 1600x900 res, and I've set `min-width: 100%` on the elements like the banner, navigation tab and the blue bar along the top.

[image]

CSS:

```
body { background-color:#F5F5F5; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:14px; margin: 0px auto; border-top: 15px solid #003663; }
.header { padding:0px 10px 0px 10px; height:170px; margin:0 auto; width:1050px; margin-top:0px; }
.container { width: 1025px; margin: 0 auto; }

div.menubar { background: #ccc; width: 100%; min-width: 100%;}
div.banner-image { overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1; }
```

HTML of the image banner:

```
    <div class="menubar">
        <div class="container">
            <ul id="topnav">
                    <?php
                    Template::Show('core_navigation.tpl');
                    ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

            <div class="banner-image">
                <div class="slicebox-wrapper">
                    <ul id="sb-slider" class="sb-slider">
                        <li><img src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro/scripts/slicebox/img/ab1.jpg" alt="image1"/></li>
                        <li><img src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro/scripts/slicebox/img/ab2.jpg" alt="image2"/></li>
                    </ul>   
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please post a minimal code example -- enough to demonstrate the problem, but without fluff.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/imimef/1 Looks OK here

Comment: Please format your code for readability.

Comment: @sachleen It does :o Very odd. I'm wondering whether the header's 1025px width could be causing it?

Answer (score 3):

this is a common problem if the background of a div has no fixed min-width. Percentages doesn't help. Background won't show in the scrollarea. You need to give it `min-width: ..px`

make it min-width: 1050px, because your header is using 1050px.

Comment: `header` looks really stretched out now but `max-width: 1050px;` fixes the issue anyhow. Thank you :)